# Access elements from list of lists by index

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

I have a list of lists like:

```
[ ['key1287', 'key5842', 'key3209','key5940', 'key42158', 'key43402', 'key31877', 'key51205', 'key2886'], 
  ['key41931', 'key41931', 'key41931', 'key41931'], 
  ['key453','key0090'], 
  ['key45333','key5432'],
  ['key453313','key51432'] ]
```

How can I access the elements one by one of the first and second index?

Thanks in advance.

**EDITED**

Suppose I have a list of many lists. The lenth of the list in unknown. Suppose 30000. After some calculation i end up that i want to take the elements (one-by-one) of the 30 and 31 index of the list. Also these indexes is not known. I know of them in runtime. Can someone help me with this?

Thank you again.

Comment: With a *nested* `for` loop...

Comment: do you mean the first 2 lists in your large list there?

Comment: `(element for sublist in lists for element in sublist[:2])`

Comment: What did you mean by "of the first and second index"?

Comment: the elements one by one of the first an second index of the large list.

Comment: `for item in my_list[0]:`  to access elements in your first index. Similar for the 2nd index?

Comment: [`chain.from_iterable(list_of_lists[index:index + 2])`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable)

Comment: Suppose i have a list of 3000 sublists. And i want to take two of them according to an index, lets say 30. This index is not known so i search a general solution for this

Comment: Btw you should've included all of this in the question to begin with. No such thing as too clear a question. Having a small sample set of data is a good start. Providing a sample of desired output even better. Showing the actual code you're having trouble with pretty much required, or you'll get a lot of "SO is not a code writing service" comments.

Comment: i agree.But i cannot post the code because connected  with many functions.

Comment: That's when you have to reduce it down to a bare minimal, complete and verifiable example. Remove the unnecessary, leaving just what you're after – in this case the "get a couple of sublists from a list of lists". You don't need to post your current code as is. In producing said minimal example you might even find the answer yourself :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a slice at the desired position and [chain](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) the results:

```
def get_sublist_items(the_list, index=0, n=2):
    return chain.from_iterable(the_list[index:index + n])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for key in listoflists[0]+listoflists[1]:
   # do your magic
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using chain:

```
from itertools import chain
superlist = [["a", "b"], ["c", "d"], ["e", "f"]]
for element in chain(superlist[0], superlist[1]):
    print(element)
# or
for element in chain.from_iterable(superlist[0:2])
    print(element)
```

They both output:

```
a
b
c
d
```

Chain iterates over the first list until completed, then begins with the following and so on. 
This is quite efficient due to not needing to create a new list that is the sum of the lists you want to iterate over.

Update:

If the indexes may vary you can do the following:

```
def get_sublist(superlist, index, n):
    return chain.from_iterable(superlist[index:index + n])

for element in get_sublist(superlist, 30, 2):
    print(element)
```

Answer (score 0):

You want the first and second element of the sublists right?

```
your_list = [ ['key1287', 'key5842', 'key3209','key5940', 'key42158', 'key43402', 'key31877', 'key51205', 'key2886'], 
  ['key41931', 'key41931', 'key41931', 'key41931'], 
  ['key453','key0090'], 
  ['key45333','key5432'],
  ['key453313','key51432'] ]
s=[(sublist[0],sublist[1]) for sublist in your_list]

print(s)
```

output:

```
[('key1287', 'key5842'), ('key41931', 'key41931'), ('key453', 'key0090'), ('key45333', 'key5432'), ('key453313', 'key51432')]
```